# Do something ONLY ONCE if screen width is less than ...px

Tags: javascript

I only want to use my function once. not everytime I resize.

Do you think this is possible?

```
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    const html = document.querySelector(".js-nav");
    if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1069px)").matches) {
        html.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
    } else {
        html.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
    }
  })
```

this is my code atm, it  translateX's every time I resize and it only has to happen once I change between a screen bigger or smaller than 1069px (because I also change the translateX with a button, and else it gets messed up when I resize again).

Comment: If you want to do it only once that's a sign you need a variable to track if you've done it or not already.

Comment: Add a counter and check the counter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to see if that function has already been executed, like:

```
var wasResized = false;
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (!wasResized) {
        const html = document.querySelector(".js-nav");
        if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1069px)").matches) {
            html.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
        } else {
            html.style.transform = "translateX(300px)";
        }
        wasResized = true;
    }
    
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the snippit in the larger page format `Expand snippit` button below the snippit and resize your browser so the snippit page is smaller than the 1069px width, then resize your browser and see the event fire only once when the conditional has been meet. The console will display the current window.innerWidth as the event fires each time you resize the browser.

*Use a conditional with a counter and set the conditional to only fire when the counter is set to **`0`.***

```js
// this is for display purposes only
let fired = document.getElementById('fired');

// below is a working example of this same method using a counter set to zero
// when the event listener fires, it runs the function and checks to see if the
// counter is set to zero, if it is run the code and add one to the counter
// affectively making the event listener inactive as the function will no longer run
// the conditional as it is not matching the condition required to fire any longer
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let x = 0;
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1069px)").matches && x === 0) {
    x++;
    // run your code you only want to run once here
    fired.textContent = "The event has fired " + x + " time @ " + window.innerWidth + " inner.width";
    console.log("counter: " + x,' min-width matches: 1069px')
  } else {
    // run other code that will not fit into your conditionals params here
    console.log("counter: " + x," => Windows inner width: " + window.innerWidth)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="fired"></div>
```